# how can i get the result of the output clause in an update statement

Tags: c++, t-sql, ado

im programming in c++ using ado, the documnet on tsql says the OUTPUT clause can return the result to the calling program, is there anyway i can retrieve it with ado in c++ ? if it is possible how to do that ?

Comment: Please mark the answer if it works for you, if not, leave comments and I'll update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup an extra parameter in your ADO object and have the parameter direction as output. Then have your original update statement define an extra variable (which is the output variable) and assign your result to that output variable.